# How to preselect struts html:radio button

Tags: struts-1

How to preselect struts 1 html:radio button?

Thanks 
Maria

Answer (score 12):

You should have a value in your `Form` object that holds the data for your radio button. You'll need to pre-fill that in your `Form` before forwarding to the JSP (or default it in the `Form`'s constructor if it will always default to that value).

**Action.java**

```
form.setRadioValue("123");
```

**View.jsp**

```
<html:radio property="radioValue" value="123" />  // <-- this radio will be checked
<html:radio property="radioValue" value="456" />  // <-- this radio will not be checked
```