# How to do a default selection of <html:radio> button

Tags: java, jsp, radio-button, selection, default

When using forms in jsp,
I am unsure how to select a radio button by default on jsp load,

```
<tr>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>
            <html:radio property="statusNew" value="I">Inactive</html:radio>
            <html:radio property="statusNew" value="A">Active</html:radio>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I am unable to do the below for html radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" property="statusNew"  value="I" checked="checked">Inactive</input>
```

Any help on this is much appreciated

Comment: Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883008/how-to-preselect-struts-htmlradio-button

Comment: Thanks.. it worked when setting the value in the action form..

Answer (score 1):

I am using default radio button in JSP..

for which the attribute and value is as below..

`checked="true"`

same should work for you!

Comment: Sorry this cannot be used with <html:radio>

Comment: in that case only try `checked` without any values

Comment: it is not an attribute for <html:radio>

Comment: works on a <form:radiobutton> in jsp